# Problems with ko.protectedObservable in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js

Could you help me with strange problem in IE11? Main problem that sometimes when you clicked to radio button and confirm to change value, it reality not apply for visible binding. It means that value not changed. I don't have any idea why it not work as inspected in IE, for example in Chrome all works very well.

**HTML**

```
<p>Send me spam: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: wantsSpam" /></p>
<div data-bind="visible: wantsSpam">
    Preferred flavor of spam:
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, event: { change: onChange }" /> Cherry</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, event: { change: onChange} " /> Almond</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, event: { change: onChange} " /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
</div>
<span data-bind="visible: isVisible">Text</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
ko.protectedObservable = function (initialValue) {
    //private variables
    var _actualValue = ko.observable(initialValue);
    var _tempValue = initialValue;

    //computed observable that we will return
    var result = ko.computed({
        //always return the actual value
        read: function () {
            return _actualValue();
        },
        //stored in a temporary spot until commit
        write: function (newValue) {
            _tempValue = newValue;
        }
    }).extend({
        notify: "always"
    });

    //if different, commit temp value
    result.commit = function () {
        if (_tempValue !== _actualValue()) {
            _actualValue(_tempValue);
        }
    };

    //force subscribers to take original
    result.reset = function () {
        _actualValue.valueHasMutated();
        _tempValue = _actualValue(); //reset temp value
    };

    return result; };

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.wantsSpam = ko.observable(true);
    self.spamFlavor = ko.protectedObservable();
    self.onChange = function () {
        debugger;
        var conf = confirm("Do you want change?")
        if (conf) {
            self.spamFlavor.commit();
        }
        else {
            self.spamFlavor.reset();
        }
    };
    self.isVisible = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        if (self.spamFlavor() === "cherry") {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }, this); };

ko.applyBindings(viewModel());
```

**Here is my code in jsfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/stanislavmachel/9s5uw75g/3/

Please try it to better understand behavior problem which is appears in IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to change the value of the element within a change handler before it was able to resolve the change.  It'll be easier to intercept the clicks instead and let the event propagate to the control if it is confirmed by returning `true` from the handler.  If it is canceled, then you will want to prevent the propagation by returning `false`.

```
<div data-bind="visible: wantsSpam">
    Preferred flavor of spam:
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry"
                data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, click: confirmChange"> Cherry</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond"
                data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, click: confirmChange"> Almond</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg"
                data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, click: confirmChange"> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
</div>
```

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.wantsSpam = ko.observable(true);
    this.spamFlavor = ko.protectedObservable();
    this.isVisible = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return this.spamFlavor() !== "cherry";
    }, this);

    this.confirmChange = function () {
        var confirmed = confirm("Do you want change?");
        if (confirmed)
            self.spamFlavor.commit();
        else
            self.spamFlavor.reset();
        return confirmed;
    };
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9s5uw75g/9/

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helps me.